# NodeJS session not persisted/retrieved

Tags: session, node.js

I'm trying to do some session authentication with node. This piece of code works fine when I run it on my localhost but the session is not retrieved when on a remote server.

Every time I hit the remote server, I can see that a new session id is generated whereas it stays the same on localhost.

Note that I'm accessing the URL directly with the browser through an ip address (no client side JS). The problem originally appeared with expressJS/jquery but I managed to reproduce with this following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: "keyboard cat" }));
    app.use(app.router);
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    // Perhaps we posted several items with a form
    // (use the bodyParser() middleware for this)
    req.session.loggedIn = true;
    var msg = "You are logged In. SessionId:"+req.session.id;
    console.log(msg);
    res.end(msg);
});

app.get('/isLoggedIn', function(req, res){
    var msg = "isLoggedIn: "+req.session.loggedIn+" SessionId:"+req.session.id;
    console.log(msg);
    res.end(msg);
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.session.destroy();
    var msg = "Logged out";
    console.log(msg);
    res.end(msg);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Do you know what may be wrong ?

node: v0.4.12
connect: v1.7.1

Thanks,
- Nicolas

Comment: this code looks very messy. pls look at the connect/express guidelines or examples to clean this up a bit: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Comment: Thank you for your concern. Thankfully this is not production code. and you can see that it's not using expressJS. I'll post a cleaner code with expressJS if you can understand it better.

Comment: I changed to an express JS implementation. Same issue. It's working on localhost. not on my remote server.

Comment: ahhh, this is much easier on the eye ;) ok, the session id changes but how about the other values you save inside the session - do they change/are missing as well?

Comment: here is also a good example: http://pastebin.com/JLUenV2r

Comment: Yes, everything is lost. The code above is running here: http://178.79.186.224:3000/login

Comment: The thing that bugs me is that the code works correctly on localhost but not on the remote server. I guess I need to fully debug it tonight :)

Comment: remember: when you deploying this on your production server, you also have to change the `NODE_ENV` from 'development' to 'production' and then use db-stored sessions instead of the built-in memory-based ones.

Comment: hi i'm having a smilar problem, and i found (in my case) that it was related to the cookie domain, did you found any solution to your problem ? thx!

Comment: @kastormania, I also found it was related to the domain and I worked around the bug by using SSL. 

It was something I could only reproduce with one computer hence likely a bug on the browser.

Try using a different domain. That should rule out server issues.